# How to populate TableView dynamically with FXML and JavaFX

Tags: javafx-2, fxml

How do I define my table in FXML and then use my JavaFX code to populate it dynamically at runtime?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Define the TableView in the fxml file. Few things to note:

   - the root should have a controller class associated with it.
   - the TableView and TableColumn should have fx:id attributes specified.

`<BorderPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="com.example.MyController">
    <center>
        <ScrollPane disable="false" visible="true">
            <content>
                <TableView fx:id="myTableView" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0">
                    <columns>
                        <TableColumn fx:id="idColumn" prefWidth="100.0" text="Id" />
                    </columns>
                </TableView>
            </content>
        </ScrollPane>
    </center>
</BorderPane>`

2. Define the controller class. Few things to note:

   - the variables should be linked with the @FXML tag and a new object of
     TableView/TableColumn should not be created.
   - the variables should be named the same as the corresponding attribute value of fx:id as
     mentioned in the fxml.
   - the controller class should implement javafx.fxml.Initializable and hence should define the method public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources)
   - a class Data Model class MyDataModel is used to populate the data.

     public class MyController implements Initializable {

     ```
     @FXML
     private TableView<MyDataModel> myTableView;

     @FXML
     private TableColumn<MyDataModel, String> idColumn;

     @Override
     public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
     idColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<MyDataModel, String>"idColumn"));

     myTableView.getItems().setAll(getItemsToAdd());
     }

     private List<MyDataModel> getItemsToAdd(){
     // this method would fetch the necessary items from database.
     }
     ```

     }
3. Define the Data Model class. Few things to note:

   - the variable should be named as idColumnProperty as the string passed for PropertyValueFactory is "idColumn".
   - the variable must be private final SimpleStringProperty as the type mentioned in controller class is String for the column.
   - the model class must have the methods getIdColumn() and setIdColumn(String id)

     public class MyDataModel {

     ```
     private final SimpleStringProperty idColumnProperty = new SimpleStringProperty("");

     public MyDataModel(){
     this("");
     }

     public MyDataModel(String id){
     setIdColumn(id);    
     }

     public String getIdColumn(){
     idColumnProperty.get();
     }

     public void setIdColumn(String id){
     idColumnProperty.set(id);
     }
     ```

     }