# Javafx 8 : Populating a TableView in initialize method

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I'm new to JavaFX 8 and I am trying to feed a TableView with some data in the controller using the initialize method.
I have seen a lot of topic on it, try a lot of stuff but it didn't work for me.
 I've seen :

- [How to populate TableView dynamically with FXML and JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26555828/how-to-populate-tableview-dynamically-with-fxml-and-javafx)
- [How to populate a TableView that is defined in an fxml file that is designed in JavaFx Scene Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180884/how-to-populate-a-tableview-that-is-defined-in-an-fxml-file-that-is-designed-in)
- [Javafx PropertyValueFactory not populating Tableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035478/javafx-propertyvaluefactory-not-populating-tableview)

and a lot more but none of the solutions happend to work for me.

Here is my code :
**class Employee**

```
public class Employee extends Person{

private SimpleIntegerProperty salary;
private SimpleObjectProperty<Character> droit;

public Employee(){
    super();
    this.salary = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    this.droit = new SimpleObjectProperty<Character>();
}

public Employee(int id, String firstName, String lastName, String password, char droits, int salary) {
    super(id,firstName,lastName,password);
    this.salary = new SimpleIntegerProperty(salary);
    this.droit = new SimpleObjectProperty<Character>(droits);
}

public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, String password, char droits, int salary) {
    super(firstName,lastName,password);
    this.salary = new SimpleIntegerProperty(salary);
    this.droit = new SimpleObjectProperty<Character>(droits);
}

...

}
```

**class Person**

```
public class Person {

protected SimpleStringProperty firstName;
protected SimpleStringProperty lastName;

public Person(){
this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty();
this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(); 

}

public Person(String firstName, String lastName){
    this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(firstName);
    this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lastName);
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName.get();
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName.set(firstName);
}

public StringProperty firstNameProperty(){
    return this.firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return this.lastName.get();
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName.set(lastName);
}

public StringProperty lastNameProperty(){
    return this.lastName;
}
```

Here is the FXML that defines the User Interface :

**ConsultHR.fxml**

```
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

    <VBox fx:id="ConsultHR" maxHeight="600.0" maxWidth="600.0" minHeight="500.0" minWidth="500.0" prefHeight="550.0" prefWidth="550.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="fr.kaf.app.controller.hr.ConsultHRController">
        <children>
            <HBox maxHeight="450.0" minHeight="450.0" prefHeight="450.0">
                <children>
                    <TableView fx:id="table" prefHeight="426.0" prefWidth="288.0">
                        <columns>
                            <TableColumn fx:id="lastNameCol" prefWidth="131.0" text="Nom" />
                            <TableColumn fx:id="firstNameCol" prefWidth="154.0" text="Prénom" />
                        </columns>
                    </TableView>
                </HBox>
                    <ButtonBar prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="400.0">
                        <buttons>
                            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#goHRAction" text="Rssources Humaines" />
                        </buttons>
                        <VBox.margin>
                            <Insets right="15.0" />
                        </VBox.margin>
               </ButtonBar>
            </children>
        </VBox>
```

And finally Here is the Controller : 
** class ConsultHRController **

```
    public class ConsultHRController extends DefaultController implements Initializable{

    @FXML
    VBox ConsultHR;

    @FXML
    public TableView<Employee> table;

    @FXML
    TableColumn<Employee,String> firstNameCol;

    @FXML
    TableColumn<Employee,String> lastNameCol;

    DAO<Employee> dao;

    SimpleListProperty<Employee> employees;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources){
        super.initialize();
        dao = (DAO<Employee>) dFact.getEmployeeDAO();
        try {
            employees = dao.findAll();
            System.out.println(employees.get());    
            table =new TableView<Employee>(employees);
            firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Employee, String>("firstName"));
            lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Employee, String>("lastName"));
            table.getColumns().setAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol);
            System.out.println(firstNameCol.getCellData(0));
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Mettre une popup erreur base de données
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void goHRAction(ActionEvent e) throws IOException{
        goSmwhereAction((Stage) ConsultHR.getScene().getWindow(),"/fr/kaf/app/fxml/hr/HumanRessources.fxml");   
    }

}
```

As you can see I have a "System.out.println(firstNameCol.getCellData(0));" in the initialize method. It results in giving me that the cell is not empty and it's filled in with the good data but I don't see anything in my UI.

Comment: Where do you assign the property fields???

Comment: I have a constructor for each class, I didn't put them in here to avoid to pollute the important part of the code. I will update it to make it clearer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You replace your `TableView` in your `initialize` method.

```
table =new TableView<Employee>(employees);
```

You assign the data to the new `TableView` and leave the one created from the fxml empty.

Instead use the one injected by the `FXMLLoader`:

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources){
    super.initialize();
    dao = (DAO<Employee>) dFact.getEmployeeDAO();
    try {
        employees = dao.findAll();

        // set data for the table created by the FXMLLoader
        table.setItems(employees);

        // no need to add them to the table since the FXMLLoader is ready doing that
        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("firstName"));
        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("lastName"));
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Mettre une popup erreur base de données
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It works now, I still don't get why instancing a new TableView doesn't work, it should re-instanciate the one injected by the FXML Loader right ?
Thank you for your advice again

Comment: @Kyle_jumpen: It overwrites the field's value with a new `TableView`. This does not mean it modifies the scene in any way. The old `TableView` is still the one that is the child of the `HBox`. It's similar to the following scenario: You've got a `List list`. `Object v = list.get(0); v = "Hello World";` The list never is modified in this code snippet; only the value of the variable you used to store the first element's value is modified.

Comment: I get it ! I wasn't aware of how the injection work. 
Thanks again.